# How to use containerized PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, docker

I watched Frank P Moely's video "Learning JDBC" in Lynda. I also have some difficulties to follow the steps.

For example, in "using containerized postgreSQL, I copied the command in README  Run docker image

> "docker run --rm --name lil-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d
>   -v $HOME/srv/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 postgres", but it displayed as below:
>
> "3e26ac7466c8aec1910ae87e7bf4fff30202978e392217ae98aaa85f7f76b182
>
> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external
>   connectivity on endpoint lil-postgres
>   (28bef8efc172f5e5399bd235290fd014cacdebf5fa482dec9af204fbbbe26770):
>   Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address
>   already in use." Besides,  when I ran "Creating starter data", "psql
>   -h localhost -U postgres -f database.sql", and it said that "database.sql: No such file or directory"

I am using Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Release:    18.04

Codename:   bionic

and I also installed Docker and postgreSQL, and I do not know how to solve the problem above. Can someone help me out? Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you also post your `docker ps -a` output?  It seems like another container is already using port 5432

Comment: _"bind: address already in use"_ you already have a PostgreSQL server (or something else) running on port 5432.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If the port 5432 is already used, can I edit the command "docker run --rm --name lil-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d -v $HOME/srv/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 postgres" to use other ports? What other ports can I use? Thank you.